# Select Case Error: Object variable of With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a little macro that on click hides specific columns and on the second click shows them again.

My macro already worked with colors as a premise but my boss told me he needs it with the specific names in the Case Query.

My old macro which worked (just for your information)

```
Option Explicit
Public s As Integer
Sub hideColumns()
   Dim c As Range
    If s = 0 Then
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(4).Cells
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c
    s = 1
    ElseIf s = 1 Then
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(4).Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
    s = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

And my new macro with string comparison which doesn't work.

```
Option Explicit
Public s As Integer
Sub hideColumns()
   Dim c As Range
    If s = 0 Then
    Select Case c.Value
    Case "SNR-A", "SNRBEZ-A", "DEPTCO-A", "NW-A", "WPKURS-A", "KW-A", "KUBER1-A", "AKS-TEAMGR"
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Case Else
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End Select
    s = 1
    ElseIf s = 1 Then
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(4).Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
    s = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

I always get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set" and I cant figure out why.

Comment: `Select Case c.Value` raises the error? You have defined `Dim c as Range` but you have not *assigned* anything to the variable `c`. So you get the error because at runtime, `c = Nothing`.

Comment: Okay, i understood. I added this line of code "Set c = Rows(4).Cells" under my definition of c. But now i got a Runtime Error 13: Type mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting "object variable not set" because you're making a member call against an object variable whose reference is not set. In the first snippet, `c` is assigned by the `For Each` iterator, so member calls against `c` are legal inside the loop body:

> ```
>    Dim c As Range
>     If s = 0 Then
>     For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(4).Cells
>         If c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
>         c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
>         End If
>     Next c
> ```

In the second/errorring snippet, the members of `c` are accessed before `c` is assigned to anything:

> ```
>    Dim c As Range
>     If s = 0 Then
>     Select Case c.Value
> ```

That will raise run-time error 91 every single time. You need to `Set c = SomeRangeOnSomeSheet` before you can access `c.Value`. Without a `Set` assignment, the value of `c` is `Nothing`.

Comment: Okay, i understood. I added this line of code "Set c = Rows(4).Cells" under my definition of c. But now i got a Runtime Error 13: Type mismatch

Comment: @PatrickSchwarz verify that none of the cells contain worksheet error values (`#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, etc.). Use the `IsError` function to do that, and don't compare error values with anything.

Comment: Is an empty cell not counted as a cell with an empty string? Maybe i have to set an boundary so my code doesnt iterate over every cell in my 4. row?

Comment: Well you *are* telling it to iterate `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(4).Cells` - might want to fine-tune that ;-)  an empty cell's value is `Variant/Empty` if there's no formula, no value, nothing in the cell; you can verify that with the `IsEmpty` function. `Variant/Empty` will happily implicitly convert to `""` (or `0`) for comparisons, but you'll still be iterating over 16K columns.. best fine-tune the range being iterated over.

Comment: Drop the .Select